# how can i manage multi-files and folders in java?

Tags: java, swing, file, netbeans, jframe

im new in the development of a compiler, i am in the university and i have a project where i need to built a compiler.

in my project i need to implement a file viewer in a part of a java frame, for example like the project explorer of netbeans where we can find all the folders and files involved in the actual project in order, i am need in manage of files and i dont have any idea of where start, i dont known if you can help my in guide me where can i start or a example of getting all de files and folders, and, how can i view in the jframe in roder like netbeans all de components,

example of files viewr in the jframe:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DScNk.png]

like in the picture, or you can guide me please, thank you for all your responces and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where can i start or a example of getting all de files and folders

Take a look at the `File.listFiles(...)` method.

You can get a list of all the files/directors for a given path. Then you just use recursion to find all the sub directories and files.

Comment: ajam, and when i have every file, how can i show in a JFrame the name so that when a name where just click on that file will open it or give me the path of that file, 
sorry for the disturbances

Comment: @EdwinAguilar, you would use a JTree. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more information and working examples.